# Combine streams of array and single value

Tags: rxjs

I have a scenario I would like help with figuring out how to implement it in rxjs.

**Source Observables:**

- `single`: emits single values with an id field
- `many`: emits array of values of the same type as `single`

**Stream Requirements:**

Overview: the final result of the stream is an array of values representing the latest value emitted from `many` overwritten by the values emitted by `single` since the last emit from `many`.

- nothing is emitted till `many` emits at least once
- the values emitted by `single` accumulate and overwrite the corresponding values (by id) previously emitted by `many`
- when `many` emits the accumulated `single` values are cleared

**Practical Scenario:**

I have a filterable data-table component that has child components that represent each filter for each column. A list of filter settings corresponding to each column (`many`) can be pushed down into the component from its parent. The child filter components can emit filter changes (`single`) for themselves. The settings from the parent component have priority over the child filter components.

**What I've Tried**

```js
console.clear();
const many = Rx.Observable.create(o => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next([
      { id: 1, value: 'a' },
      { id: 2, value: 'b' },
      { id: 3, value: 'c' }
    ]);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    o.next([
      { id: 1, value: 'x' },
      { id: 2, value: 'y' },
      { id: 3, value: 'z' }
    ]);
  }, 4000);
});

const single = Rx.Observable.create(o => {
  o.next({ id: 1, value: 'd' });
  setTimeout(() => { o.next({ id: 2, value: 'e' }); }, 2000);
  setTimeout(() => { o.next({ id: 3, value: 'f' }); }, 3000);
  setTimeout(() => { o.next({ id: 1, value: 'g' }); }, 5000);
});

single
  .scan((acc, x) => {
    return [...acc.filter(y => y.id !== x.id), x];
  }, [])
  .startWith([])
  .combineLatest(many)
  .map(x => {
    const s = x[0];
    const m = x[1];
    return [...m.filter(y => !s.some(z => z.id === y.id)), s];
  })
  .subscribe(x => { console.log(JSON.stringify(x)); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

What this code doesn't do reset the accumulated `single` values when `many` emits.

**Question**

How do you implement the afore mentioned scenario in rxjs?

### Edit

I found a solution (posted bellow) but I'll accept a better implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blaaah... I realized what I did wrong soon after posting. I just needed to reverse the order. Here is my solution but I'm open to better options.

```js
const many = new Rx.Subject();
const single = new Rx.Subject();

// create the stream
const stream = many
  .switchMap(m => {
    return single
      .scan((acc, x) => {
        return [...acc.filter(y => y.id !== x.id), x];
      }, [])
      .startWith([])
      .map(s => {
        return [...m.filter(y => !s.some(z => z.id === y.id)), ...s];
      });
  })
  .subscribe(x => { console.log(JSON.stringify(x)); });

// send the data
single.next({ id: 1, value: 'd' });
setTimeout(() => {
  many.next([
    { id: 1, value: 'a' },
    { id: 2, value: 'b' },
    { id: 3, value: 'c' }
  ]);
}, 1000);
setTimeout(() => { single.next({ id: 2, value: 'e' }); }, 2000);
setTimeout(() => { single.next({ id: 3, value: 'f' }); }, 3000);
setTimeout(() => {
  many.next([
    { id: 1, value: 'x' },
    { id: 2, value: 'y' },
    { id: 3, value: 'z' }
  ]);
}, 4000);
setTimeout(() => { single.next({ id: 1, value: 'g' }); }, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```